# Set properties from .properties file in .jar on JVM startup

Tags: java, maven-2, properties, jar

How can I setup the JVM to automatically load a .properties file in .jar on the classpath on JVM startup? I do not want to configure the properties on the commandline (with -D) but have them in a .properties file.

Is there a way to configure this with the help of Maven?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have the system properties loaded from a file automatically. What you can do is have some sort of launcher that reads a file and automatically "translates" it to -D command line options.

Java WebStart does something like that, with system properties defined in the [JNLP file](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) - maybe you can use that.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Maven to package your application, consider using the appassembler-maven-plugin's [generate-daemons](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/generate-daemons-mojo.html) goal. This will generate JSW based daemon wrappers for Windows and linux. So the bat/sh file used to launch the application will have those properties defined, while still allowing you to specify additional properties via the command line.

You can specify in the execution the [defaultJVMSettings](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/generate-daemons-mojo.html#defaultJvmSettings) property so that the JVM will be launched with those properties. The example below shows how these settings can be defined:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <execution>
    <id>generate-jsw-scripts</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <defaultJvmSettings>
        <initialMemorySize>256M</initialMemorySize>
        <maxMemorySize>1024M</maxMemorySize>
        <systemProperties>
          <systemProperty>java.security.policy=conf/policy.all</systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>com.sun.management.jmxremote</systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999</systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>
            com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
          </systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false</systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <extraArguments>
          <extraArgument>-server</extraArgument>
        </extraArguments>
      </defaultJvmSettings>
      <daemons>
        <daemon>
          <id>myApp</id>
          <mainClass>name.seller.rich.MainClass</mainClass>
          <commandLineArguments>
            <commandLineArgument>start</commandLineArgument>
          </commandLineArguments>
          <platforms>
            <platform>windows</platform>
            <platform>unix</platform>
          </platforms>
        </daemon>
      </daemons>
      <target>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</target>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That's a great solution for a standalone app, but in my case I have a library. And I want to bundle the properties with this lib in a way, that every time it is used, the bundled properties are set. So basically I would have to do it in the source code.