# Is there a way to pass all properties from a property-file as JVM params?

Tags: java, properties

We can pass a single property through java CLI using `-D` argument:

`java -Dkey=value ...`

Is there a way to pass all properties from a property file in that way?

Something like:

`java -Dprop.file=myproperties.properties ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set properties from .properties file in .jar on JVM startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470607/set-properties-from-properties-file-in-jar-on-jvm-startup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you add

```
System.getProperties().load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("prop.file")));
```

Comment: He didn't say he cannot change the code. I assumed he was a developer and knows sometimes you have to write some code to do things.

Comment: Even if he didn't know that (and I suppose he did), some properties cannot be change at runtime, so it doesn't fully solve the problem.

Comment: @Viruzzo, you are right that changing some system properties have no effect. If your SecurityManager allows it you can change any property.

Comment: Even memory options, classpath, optimization flags? I would doubt that.

Comment: @Viruzzo, Can you give an example of such a flag which is set with `-D` ?

Comment: Whooops my bad, I got carried away and forgot we where talking about -D.

Comment: -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high= ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code with

```
new Properties().load(...)
```

of course, but from command line the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) talks only about key=val

Be aware that there are some keys (eg. java.library.path) that must be set before your program runs and reseting in your code will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option for java cli.

But this task can be achieved from command line with simple ant's build.xml using [loadproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) and [syspropertyset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659403/ant-passing-all-parameters-to-a-java-task/).